# Qual a diferença de uma toolbar para uma action bar?

Tags: android, android-layout

Já pesquisei muito sobre e não achei nada que pudesse explicar isso. Existe diferença ou é a mesma coisa?

Comment: Nunca pensei nisso, que foi porque eu nunca tinha utilizado uma função action bar, sempre usei o NoActionBar e dentro da toolbar eu fazia a ação

Answer (score 6, accepted):

São coisas diferentes podendo o ToolBar ser usado com o mesmo propósito do ActionBar: fornecer um [App bar](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar).

São estas as principais características de cada um:

### **[Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html)**

- É um tipo especial e dedicado de *View*.
- É posicionado na parte superior da tela.
- Qualquer aplicação, se não indicado em contrário, tem uma ActionBar.
- Ela é constituída por quatro partes: 1 - App Icon, 2 - View control, 3 - Action buttons, 4 - Action overflow
  <sub><sub>[fonte:Documentação Android - Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html)</sub></sub>
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Não é fácil de costumizar.

### **[ToolBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html)**

- É um *ViewGroup*.
- Pode ser colocado em qualquer parte do *layout*
- Pode ter associado a ele um Action Menu.
- Não tem estrutura definida, sendo um *ViewGroup*, pode conter qual tipo e número de *Views*

Comment: Tava respondendo, mas em Android nem vou tentar competir com você :)

Comment: @bigown Por que não? Eu também respondo em assuntos que você domina melhor do que eu.

Comment: Mas porque tem algo legal pra responder também, nesse caso eu não ia falar nada novo, seria menos e com menos propriedade, quase beirando ao erro :)

Comment: Entendi...Eu havia me confundido bastante...agora ficou mais claro.