# Qual a diferença entre um toolbar e uma outra view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Estou aprendendo a utilizar o `toolbar` no desenvolvimento Android e vi que o uso dele é bem parecido com outras `views`, vi que da pra colocar ele sem ser no topo, que dá pra colocar itens dentro dele (botão por exemplo), tipo um layout, ai bateu a dúvida, eu posso usar um `LinearLayout` (ou outro) como um `toolbar`?
Colocar ele no topo, definir as cores, colocar itens, etc... Quais os benefícios de usar o toolbar mesmo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) é de facto um tipo de View, mais propriamente um tipo de ViewGroup:

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.view.View
       ↳    android.view.ViewGroup
           ↳    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Como pode ver na sua hierarquia, ele herda as características de View e ViewGroup.
É por isso que é possível fazer tudo aquilo que você enumera na pergunta.

No entanto, Toolbar é muito mais do que um ViewGroup.
Ele acrescenta outras característica com o intuito de ser uma [alternativa ao ActionBar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178775/2541).

Entre elas,

- Botão de navegação.
- Logotipo.
- Título e subtítulo.
- Incluir outras views.
- Menu de acções.

Comment: Mas em um Layout (como o Linear por exemlo, que é o que mais uso) não é possível fazer isso tudo? Se sim, porque usar um toolbar? por já ser criado devidamente pra isso e ser mais simples?

Comment: Sim é possível. No fundo é o que foi feito por quem fez o Toolbar, partiu de um ViewGroup. Qual a razão para você fazer o que já está feito?

Comment: Ah entendi então, muito obrigado aí, era uma dúvida simples, mas agora está tudo ok, agora vou voltar pros códigos!